# Comparing Power BI/Excel Reports

Tags: excel, powerbi

I'm working on a project where I receive a list in excel of employee names, dates and ID's. I need to compare this list to a Power BI report that I've made to bring back any ID's that are locked.
For example:
I receive

```
| Employee Name | Date      | ID |
| ------------- | --------- | -- |
| John Doe      | 4/22/21   | 1 |
| Jane Doe      | 4/23/21   | 2 |
The Power BI Report looks like this:
| Employee Name | Date           | ID | LOCK?    |
| ------------- | -------------- | -- | -------- |
| John Doe      | 4/22/21        | 1  | LOCK     |
| Jane Doe      | 4/23/21        | 2  | UNLOCKED |
```

Is there a way to compare a my list in excel with my a Power BI on a large scale? I've tried Power Query in Excel, but the data is too large.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using a pbiviz file (Filter By List)